# Python 3: Removing brackets from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Im trying to remove brackets from a list array, but its not working, heres my code.

```
#user input for amount of directories
ask_total_dirs = 100

#begin calculation
num_files = 10 #sets how many files per directory
total_files = int((ask_total_dirs * num_files)) #finds total amount of files
#print (total_files)

phone_num = 50000 #total number of phone numbers per file
total_phone_num = (total_files * phone_num) #total number of phone numbers
#print (total_phone_num)
#end calculation

#begin generator code
def area_code():
    area = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(3)] #set for area code
    list_area = str(list(area))
    multiply = str(list_area * total_files) #all amount of area codes needed
    nospace = ( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in multiply ) )
    print (nospace)

area_code()
#end generator code
```

I get the output of...

```
'[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']', '[', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '8', ']'
```

I have also tried this code but I get the same output.

```
nospace = "".join(multiply)
```

any help is appreciated

EDIT

fyi, i had to cut these arrays short because theyre way too long because of the static variable numbers I set.

when I do print(multiply) before nospace, this is the output I get.

```
[4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5][4, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What output do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you make everything into a string?

Comment: I want to have no brackets. just commas between each list. @jonrsharpe just easier for me to set for now, going to change it later.

Comment: Well you say that, but evidently it isn't easier, because it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
multiply = multiply.replace('[','').replace(']','')
```

It will remove all brackets from the string multiply.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Question, would it be possible to add another .replace to the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
list = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
print("The list contains: ")
for a in range (0, len(list)):
    print("- " + list[a])
```

This works, because it prints out:
- Item 1
- Item 3
- Item 2
I suggest using this method to remove the brackets around a list. 
If you don't know how to use the `for x in range()` go to https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp to learn more about it.